# ocultar y mostrar con un boton con jquery o alguna otra manera los div uno y tres sin que afecte los espacios

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
<div id="general">
  <div id="uno">
    <p> hola soy uno</p>
  </div
     <div id="dos">
    <p> hola soy dos</p>
  </div
     <div id="tres">
    <p> hola soy tres</p>
  </div
     <div id="cuatro">
    <p> hola soy cuatro</p>
  </div>
</div>
<input id="boton" type="button" value="click">
```

Comment: Hola Delfor, no hace falta que crees una nueva pregunta, puedes editar la que ya tenías añadiendo todo tu código. Estaría bien también que pusieras el javascript que has intentado.

Answer (score 1):

Con una sencilla regla de estilo `visibility` solucionas el problema. Además, no hace falta jQuery para esto, es bastante sencillo usando JS puro

```js
function toggleVisibility() {
  document.getElementById('uno').classList.toggle('hidden');
  document.getElementById('tres').classList.toggle('hidden');
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleVisibility()">Click me</button>
<div id="uno">Uno</div>
<div id="dos">Dos</div>
<div id="tres">Tres</div>
<div id="cuatro">Cuatro</div>
```

Comment: hola kiko gracias por tu respuesta pero me gustaria que al principio se muestren los cuatros div y a darle click al boton solo se oculte el 1 y el 3, y al volver a darle click vuelva aparecer el 1 y el 3.gracias

Comment: @delfordiazdavila si te funcionó recuerda marcar la pregunta como resuelta